# Vue Material - Triggering MdTableAlternateHeader visibility

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-material

I'm looking for a way to trigger the `MdAlternateHeader` visibility - or maybe to reset its count state.

The app in question has this multi-selection `MdTable` in which I implemented a delete function per row. But on data erasing, the alternate header still hold the `md-selected` class set to `true` (refeered to the deleted and previously selected element/row). As well as the related computed props (`isInSelectedItems` and `isMultipleSelected`).

How can I change these state? I was thinking about to trigger a "selected" or "clicked" event on the row befote its deletion, but I'm missing something on the way.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it.

I inspected the framework data and noticed this `md-selected-value` prop, contained in `MdTable` component. After declaring the prop in my component:

```
props: [
    // ...     
        'mdSelectedValue'
    ],
```

I update its value through a second array, delegated to track what elements are being selected for deletion:

```
data: () => ({
    selezionato = []
})
```

then I listen for any change in selection:

```
<md-table v-model="cercato" @md-selected="onSelezionato" md-sort="codice" md-sort-order="asc" md-card md-fixed-header :md-selected-value="selezionato">
```

In my delete function, after every deletion I reset the the new `selezionato` value, in order to disable the alternate header:

```
this.selezionato = []
```

That's it.